# Sveltekit proxy api to avoid cors

Tags: cors, svelte, sveltekit

I'm actually building a basic svelkit app.
I need to fetch to a weather api but impossible to fetch I have cors errors :
[image]

I guess I need to setup a proxy for `https://www.metaweather.com` is there any way to do it with svelte kit ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There certainly is. SvelteKit routing provides two types of routes, pages (= frontend) and endpoints (= backend).

Quoting the [SvelteKit routing docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing):

> Endpoints run only on the server (or when you build your site, if prerendering). This means it's the place to do things like **access databases or APIs that require private credentials** or return data that lives on a machine in your production network. Pages can request data from endpoints. Endpoints return JSON by default, though may also return data in other formats.

CORS is essentially a form of credentialed request, so having an endpoint acting as a proxy API is ideal.

This is what such a route would look like in your use case:

```js
// src/routes/api/weather/[city].json.js
export async function get({ params }) {
    const { city } = params;

    const res = await fetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=${city}`);
    const weather = await res.json();

    return { body: weather };    
}
```

[SvelteKit Endpoints documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints) detailing stuff like the expected format of the return object, handling POSTs requests, etc.

Once this route is up, you would access it in lieu of accessing the original API in your frontend code, for example:

```js
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/weather/${city}.json`);
```

And that's pretty much all there is to it.

**Important update for users of a newer release of SvelteKit**

In newer releases of SvelteKit, following its switch to a [slightly different routing convention](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing), the endpoint above should now be located in `src/routes/api/weather/[city].json/+server.js`. <del>Its content should still work *as-is* however.</del> (No longer true, see below).

**Update for SvelteKit 1.0+**

The structure of an endpoint handler has slightly changed in SvelteKit's 1.0 release. A proxy route would now look like the following:

```js
// src/routes/api/weather/[city].json/+server.js
export function GET({ params }) { // note the capitalized method name
    const { city } = params;

    // we can now simply pass on the original 3rd-party api response promise
    return fetch(`https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=${city}`);
}
```

Comment: I've looked at so many tutorials and SvelteKit's official documentation. Only your answer helped me.

Comment: @NetOperatorWibby Glad I could help! Your comment also reminded me to update the answer with a change in the name & location of the endpoint file to reflect changes in SvelteKit's routing convention in its more recent releases :)

Comment: Further updated to conform to SvelteKit 1.0's endpoint handler format

Comment: is it possible to provide help regarding setting a custom node server? It seems the team behind adapter-node abondened the community and no longer answering questions regarding the adapter.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76733107/adapter-node-in-sveltekit-creating-and-using-custom-node-server-cors-error   also my git is here https://github.com/fxmt2009/kitcustomserver    how to make the build  
 aware of my server and use it for the output/build instead of the vite during dev?

Comment: Docs don't mention you can pass fetch in this way! Anyone know if it's possible to adjust headers/cookies on the proxied fetch call? Also does anyone know if it pipes the response or does the svelte server download the whole response and then send?